# Does TemplateView supports pagination?

Tags: javascript, django, django-views, pagination, django-templates

How can I implement pagination with Templateview? The below view is class-based view where I am using Templateview for listing out networks ( which I am calling from api from another application). Here I am not using models so I cant use Listview because I don't have queryset.

```
class classView(TemplateView):
 
    template_name = 'view_network.html'
    # paginate_by = 5
    context_object_name = 'networks'
    paginator = Paginator('networks', 5)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    ...
    ...
    return context
```

in html page i have added this:

```
<span class="step-links" style="margin-left: 30%;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-top: 0px;
width: 100%;">
    <div style="text-align: justify"></div>
    <table style="width: 50%">
    <tr>
        {% if page_obj.has_previous %}
        <td><a href="?page=1">&laquo; First</a></td>
        <td> <a href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}">Previous</a></td>
        {% endif %}

        <td> Page {{ page_obj.number }} of {{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}.</td>

        {% if page_obj.has_next %}
        <td><a href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}">Next</a></td>
        <td><a href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}">Last &raquo;</a></td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
</span>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the pagination within the `get_context_data()` function. Assuming `networks` is a list of objects.

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    page_size = 5
    paginator = Paginator(networks, page_size)

    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    page_obj = paginator.page(page)

    context = {
        "page_obj": page_obj
    }
```

Comment: The page is changing but the data is same in all pages.

Answer (score 1):

TemplateView does not support pagination, you have to use a ListView to use "paginate_by = 5" [Here](http://ccbv.co.uk/) is a helpfull link to check all attributes/methods for each class based generic view.

Comment: I can't use ListView here.